# How to change cv::Mat image dimensions dynamically?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to declare an cv::Mat object and somewhere else in my code, change its dimension (nrows and ncols). I couldn't find any method in the documentation of OpenCV. They always suggest to include the dimension in the constuctor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An easy and clean way is to use the `create()` method. You can call it as many times as you want, and it will reallocate the image buffer when its parameters do not match the existing buffer:

```
Mat frame;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    ...
    // if width[i], height[i] or type[i] are != to those on the i-1
    // or the frame is empty(first loop)
    // it allocates new memory
    frame.create(height[i], width[i], type[i]); 
    ... 
    // do some processing
}
```

Docs are available at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a55ced2c8d844d683ea9a725c60037ad0

Comment: doesn't create() ruin the original image?  I thought you had to use resize

Comment: You are right Mat::create de-references the previous data http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-create while Mat::resize preserves it just as the STL vector class http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-resize

Comment: For reasons I'm too lazy to explain, resize() does not work as the STL containers' functions, and create() does the job in this case. It only re-allocates if new size does not match the original.

Comment: You mixed up the arguments. It's void create (int rows, int cols, int type). Thus, frame.create(height, width, type).

Answer (score 6):

If you mean to resize the image, check [`resize()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize)!

Create a new `Mat dst` with the dimensions and data type you want, then:

```
cv::resize(src, dst, dst.size(), 0, 0, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
```

There are other interpolation methods besides `cv::INTER_CUBIC`, check the docs.

Comment: Thanks karl, but my problem is that I want to define the type, and dimension of the cv::Mat object dynamically. resize() might be one solution, but it is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, I've used `resize()` for that purpose (as far as I could understand you) more times than I can count. Whenever you need to change the dimensions of your `src` Mat , all you need to do is declare a new Mat with the dimensions and type you want, and execute `resize()` so it scales the data to the new dimension. And if you want, you can still perform `src = dst.clone();` to copy redimensioned data to the original Mat.

Answer (score 3):

Do you just want to define it with a `Size` variable you compute like this?

```
// dynamically compute size...
Size dynSize(0, 0);
dynSize.width = magicWidth();
dynSize.height = magicHeight();

int dynType = CV_8UC1;
// determine the type you want...

Mat dynMat(dynSize, dynType);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I found the solution, declare cv::Mat image; and somewhere else dynamically change its properties by calling create() as image.create(magicWidth(), magicHeight(), dynType);

Comment: Yeah, `create()` should definitely do the same thing as the constructor just after you have declared the `Mat` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum dimensions and only need to use a subrange of rows/cols from the total Mat use the functions cv::Mat::rowRange and/or cv::Mat::colRange

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-rowrange