# The most efficient way to resize cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, optimization, cpu-usage

all

I'm writing an image processing program, which uses cv::resize(INTER_LINEAR) hundreds of times for one frame. However, I found cv::resize() is a cpu-killer and it is the hot spot in my program. Are there better ways to resize the image with less cpu usage?

The code is kind of like this:

```
void process(const cv::Mat& frame) {
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNTS; ++i) {
        int new_rows = CalculateHeight();
        int new_cols = CalculateWidth();
        cv::Mat new_img;
        cv::resize(frame, new_mg, cv::Size(new_cols, new_rows));
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14863158/5008845) and at [pyramids](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/pyramids/pyramids.html)

Comment: But pyrUp() & pyrDown() have a requirement of the dst size, and in my program, I don't know what size will the image be scaled to.

Comment: just multiply your rows and cols by the resize factor. If you show us some code probably you'll get better answers.

Comment: I posted the code already. I employed some way to get the new rows and columns.

Comment: here appears that the size will be always the same in the for loop... Can you explain better which (and how many) different sizes do you need for each image?

Comment: No, the size won't be the same. This sample code is simplified too much. The number of different sizes is calculated dynamiclly and they are fast. Only cv::resize() is consuming.

Comment: Well, if you need different sized images, you need to resize them, and it will be time consuming. If you have a limited number of possible sizes, you can precompute all of them, and in the for loop just get the correct resized image.

Comment: do you need linear interolation?

Comment: Yes. Linear interpolation is the best choice for my program currently.

Comment: do you have many resizes from the same image parts (identical or overlappung) to multiple output sizes? If yes there might be ways to precompute or share information for the resize calls

Answer (score 6):

Here are the results of some tests I did with resizing a random image using OpenCV functions 10,000 times. The best solution seems to be to convert to grayscale (if possible) before resizing, using ROI or rolling your own ASM AVX function to resize using every 1/3rd (or what ever scaling factor you need) row & column. The resize functions are fairly optimised.

```
Colour
INTER_LINEAR 7953.89ms
INTER_LINEAR GPU 2252.72ms
INTER_LINEAR GPU MEMIO 23303.7ms
INTER_NEAREST 7297.58ms
INTER_NEAREST GPU 906.336ms
INTER_NEAREST GPU MEMIO 22374.1ms
BORDER_DEFAULT 47488.8ms
BORDER_REFLECT 47515.4ms
BORDER_REPLICATE 47516ms
BORDER_WRAP 47980.7ms
PYR GPU 4126.93ms

Grayscale
INTER_LINEAR 413.789ms
INTER_LINEAR GPU 1027.85ms
INTER_LINEAR GPU MEMIO 9568.99ms
INTER_NEAREST 978.89ms
INTER_NEAREST GPU 747.621ms
INTER_NEAREST GPU MEMIO 9346.28ms
BORDER_DEFAULT 19266.7ms
BORDER_REFLECT 19274.1ms
BORDER_REPLICATE 19300.8ms
BORDER_WRAP 19386.3ms
PYR GPU 2272.7ms


#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudawarping.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

template <typename T>
double resizePerfEval(const Mat& frame, unsigned int n, T resizeFlag) {

    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Mat temp;
        resize(frame, temp, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, resizeFlag); 
    }

    return chrono::duration <double, milli>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
}

template <typename T>
double pyramidPerfEval(const Mat& frame, unsigned int n, T border) {

    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Size s(frame.cols / 2, frame.rows / 2);

    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Mat tmp;
        pyrDown(frame, tmp, s, border); 
    }

    return chrono::duration <double, milli>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
}

template <typename T>
double resizePerfEvalGPU(const Mat& frame, unsigned int n, T resizeFlag, bool uploadDownload=false) {

    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    Mat tmp;
    cuda::GpuMat frame_d, temp;
    frame_d.upload(frame);

    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {          

        cuda::resize(frame_d, temp, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, resizeFlag);
        if (uploadDownload) {
            temp.download(tmp);
            frame_d.upload(frame);
        }
    }

    return chrono::duration <double, milli>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
}

double pyramidPerfEvalGPU(const Mat& frame, unsigned int n, bool uploadDownload = false) {

    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    Mat tmp;
    cuda::GpuMat frame_d, temp;
    frame_d.upload(frame);

    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {      

        cuda::pyrDown(frame_d, temp);
        if (uploadDownload) {
            temp.download(tmp);
            frame_d.upload(frame);
        }

    }

    return chrono::duration <double, milli>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
}


void runTest(const Mat& frame, unsigned int n) {

    cout << "INTER_LINEAR "     << resizePerfEval(frame, n, INTER_LINEAR) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "INTER_LINEAR GPU " << resizePerfEvalGPU(frame, n, INTER_LINEAR) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "INTER_LINEAR GPU MEMIO " << resizePerfEvalGPU(frame, n, INTER_LINEAR, true) << "ms" << endl;

    cout << "INTER_NEAREST "    << resizePerfEval(frame, n, INTER_NEAREST) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "INTER_NEAREST GPU "    << resizePerfEvalGPU(frame, n, INTER_NEAREST) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "INTER_NEAREST GPU MEMIO " << resizePerfEvalGPU(frame, n, INTER_NEAREST, true) << "ms" << endl;

    cout << "BORDER_DEFAULT "   << pyramidPerfEval(frame, n, BORDER_DEFAULT) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "BORDER_REFLECT "   << pyramidPerfEval(frame, n, BORDER_REFLECT) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "BORDER_REPLICATE " << pyramidPerfEval(frame, n, BORDER_REPLICATE) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "BORDER_WRAP "      << pyramidPerfEval(frame, n, BORDER_WRAP) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "PYR GPU "          << pyramidPerfEvalGPU(frame, n) << "ms" << endl;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Mat gsframe, frame = Mat::ones(Size(1920, 1080), CV_8UC3);
    randu(frame, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(255));
    cvtColor(frame, gsframe, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    auto n = 10000;

    cout << "Colour" << endl;
    runTest(frame, n);

    cout << endl << "Grayscale" << endl;
    runTest(gsframe, n);    

    return 0;
}
```

If the algorithm is running on a PC an alternative is to do resizing on a CUDA enabled GPU. You would have to be careful in selecting the card however as you would need the memory bandwidth to be sufficiently higher to accommodate for the time taken to upload and download images from GPU memory.

Note from the results that CPU beats GPU on grayscale and when the image is unavailable on GPU memory. If the image is available on the GPU memory then for Colour its a 3.5X speed-up using GPU (specially for very large image sizes). For high end applications NVIDIA capture cards with GPUDirect can be used to achieve this.

Benchmarks were carried out on a Xeon E5 v2 @ 3.0Ghz 680GTX